# Parent/child components not reacting to changes on shared object

Tags: vue.js, vue-component

I've put an example on jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/j6hs5fmL/56/

For this question, I've created a very simple html document:

```
<div id="app">
    <my-form errors="{&quot;title&quot;: [&quot;This field is required&quot;]}">
        <my-input name="title" value=""></my-input>
    </my-form>
</div>
```

Errors are pass into `my-form` which then places them into a Collection class I've created:

```
Vue.component('my-form', {
  name: 'my-form',
  props: {
    errors: String
  },
  data() {
    let errors = new Collection(JSON.parse(this.errors));

    return {
      myErrors: errors,
      disabled: errors.any()
    }
  },
  template: `<form>
        <slot></slot>

        <input type="submit" :disabled="disabled" value="Submit">
    </form>`
});
```

The `my-input` component can then access the errors and display them:

```
Vue.component('my-input', {
  name: 'savvy-input',
  props: {
    name: String
  },
  data() {
    return {
      value: '',
      errors: this.$parent.myErrors
    }
  },
  methods: {
    blur() {
      if (this.value !== "") {
        this.errors.clear(this.name);
      }

      if (this.value === "") {
        this.errors.set(this.name, ["This input is still required"]);
      }

      this.$forceUpdate();
    }
  },
  template: `<div>
        <div v-if="errors.has(this.name)">
            <p>There are errors</p>
            <p v-for="error in errors.get(name)">{{ error }}</p>
        </div>

        <input type="text" :name="name" v-model="value" @blur="this.blur">
    </div>`
});
```

I'm now stuck on one last thing.

The input component is reacting to the changes in the error collection and removing or redisplaying the error messages.

But the form is not reacting to the changes, and the submit button is not enabling when the error collection is empty.

How do I get the parent to react to changes on the shared errors collection? Or is there a better way of sharing state between the parent form and child inputs?

Comment: Part of the problem is at least `errors: this.$parent.myErrors`. It sets the `errors` attribute once, when the component is created, but does not update `errors` based on the parent, so if a change in the parent occurs it does not reflect in the child. In any case you are probably better of by passing it as a prop in any case. Otherwise you need to use a computed property, in which case it probably works too.

Comment: @Sumurai8 how do I do what you say in this context where the child components are being added via slot?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your primary problem is that your Collection class is not reactive. It is not a plain object, so Vue doesn't do its magic with accessors on its elements. You need to create methods in your parent object that re-assign `myErrors` itself so that Vue notices changes:

```
  methods: {
    refresh() {
      const temp = this.myErrors;
      
      this.myErrors = null;
      this.myErrors = temp;
    },
    set(field, value) {
      this.myErrors.set(field, value);
      this.refresh();
    },
    clear(field) {
      this.myErrors.clear(field);
      this.refresh();
    }
  },
```

`my-input` should not have `errors` as a `data` item, because it is not an independent data object; it should be a computed:

```
errors() {
  return this.$parent.myErrors;
}
```

Rather than using a `blur` event, you should probably be `watch`ing for updates of `value` and calling the parent's methods:

```
  watch: {
    value(newValue) {
        if (newValue !== '') {
        this.$parent.clear(this.name);
      } else {
        this.$parent.set(this.name, ['This input is still required']);
      }
    }
  },
```

Put it all together and [the fiddle works](https://jsfiddle.net/j6hs5fmL/111/). This is a fairly tight coupling of the slot object and the parent, but it is [inherent in your design](https://github.com/vuejs/vue/issues/4332#issuecomment-263444492) that the slot must know something of the parent. There is probably something you could do with [scoped slots](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-slots.html#Scoped-Slots) to make things tidier.